# C Heap Allocating a Hard Coded Struct Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I am having trouble figuring out how to make a hard-coded array heap allocated.

Imagine I have the structures:

```
struct my_struct
{
    ...
};

struct holder
{
    my_struct *array_of_struct;
    ...
};
```

Now to create an instance of `struct holder` though, the array of `struct my_struct` has to be hard-coded, such as:

```
struct holder *new_holder()
{
    struct holder *my_holder = malloc(sizeof(struct holder));
    if (my_holder == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    struct my_struct arr[] = {mystruct_instace_1, mystruct_instance_2, ...};
    holder->array_of_struct = arr;
    return holder;
}
```

This assignment though wont work, because its pointing to `arr` which is stack allocated. How would I go about making this assignment of `holder->array_of_struct` heap allocated?

Comment: As a very minor point: I would name the function `new_holder()` or `holder_new()`.  As convention, "init" often means "initialize this structure that I allocated" and "new" often means "allocate and initialize".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super-lazy way to do it is just copy the array into a buffer from `malloc()`, as follows:

```
struct my_struct arr[] = {mystruct_instace_1, mystruct_instance_2, ...};
holder->array_of_struct = malloc(sizeof(arr));
assert(holder->array_of_struct);
memcpy(holder->array_of_struct, arr, sizeof(arr));
return holder;
```

By "super-lazy" I mean "minimum number of lines of code written".

Comment: In theory a compiler should optimize `arr` out here, but I wouldn't hold my breath

Comment: Note: the `assert` is just a lazy way of handling allocation failures here.